# Revealing image from left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an animation in css, jquery could be helpful, but it's not giving me desired results.

This is the image:

[image: gif]

I am talking about the black phone animation.

Animating any piece of html, is easy and I can handle it well, but this sort of image revealing  is complicated and that's where I need help.

Comment: Show what u have done so far ?

Comment: This is way too broad, and doesn’t show any real effort on your part. _“but it's not giving me desired results”_ - then at least show us what you tried. Please go read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: Sorry my friend, but the thing is that I was mugging on this one from last couple of hours and have tried various thing, but my problem was that I was trying css only method. Anyways I'll do keep in mind your suggestion from next time onwards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want :

```js
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('.mask').width(i+"%");
  i++;
  if (i === 101) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},10);
```

```css
.mask {
  background:white;
  max-width: 640px;
  z-index:1;
  height: 426px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mask">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking pain in replying me, and I firmly believe that you are a rock-star.

Comment: Also can you please help me in getting same animation done from right to left, instead of left to right.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('.mask').css({left:-i+"%"});
  i++;
  if (i === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},10);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 640px;
  height: 430px;
  position: relative;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mask">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <script>
        function topInViewport(element) {
            return $(element).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop() && $(element).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        }
 </script>
    <script>
     $(window).on("resize scroll", function (e) {
            topInViewport($('.mask'))
        });
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
                $('.mask').width(i + "%");
                i++;
                if (i == 101) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
        }, 20);
    </script>

Comment: I tried upvoting but got message that my vote has been recorded although it can not be publicly displayed as my reputation is less than 15.

I tried to merge the code with viewport but messed it up, the code tried has been displayed in my previous message. Any suggestions?

Comment: And when it worked just below following words "THE QUICK AND BEAUTIFUL", their is jerking in the movement.
The URL where I uploaded is 'tecnoweb.bottlementors.com'